# dyld: library not loaded on mac os

Tags: macos, terminal, shared-libraries

I am trying to run the nii2mnc command from minc tools in a Terminal on Mac OS 10.11.1 and received the following error.

The "/usr/local/bic/lib/libvolume_io2.1.dylib" does not exist though, but the dylib files are under "/opt/local/bic/lib".

Any help would be highly appreciated.

$ /opt/local/bic/bin/nii2mnc testing.nii testing.mnc
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/bic/lib/libvolume_io2.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bic/bin/nii2mnc
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5

Comment: Your library path appears not to be set.  Depends on how you installed how you want to set it or if that's the only issue you'll have

Comment: You can change the library reference using `install_name_tool`.